# choosing mail account in applescript

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I'd like to send a mail using a Mac Automator action. I prepared the following mail script:

```
set recipientName to "<recipient>"
set recipientAddress to "<recipient mail address>"
set theSubject to "<mail subject>"
set textBody to "<text>"

tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:textBody, visible:true}
    --set recipient
    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}
        --send the message
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

now when I send this it uses the Account that is basically currently selected (highlighted) in the Mail App.

Is there any way to choose a specific account?

Comment: hey @Dragon5689 how did this go? Did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `sender` of theMessage to a valid address of one of your accounts.

e.g.

```
set recipientName to "<recipient>"
set recipientAddress to "<recipient mail address>"
set theSubject to "<mail subject>"
set textBody to "<text>"
set theSender to "dragon5689@stackoverflow.com" -- your valid account email here 

tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:textBody, visible:true, sender:theSender}
    tell theMessage
        make new to recipient with properties {name:recipientName, address:recipientAddress}
        send
    end tell
end tell
```